# Key error when making items in a particular column as keys in python dictionary

Tags: python, csv

Below is a sample of my csv file (I have only included the first row but I have hundreds of rows):

```
Name, Value [abc/g]
abc_123_def.77, 4.954172
```

I want to make the contents of "Name" as keys meanwhile the value for this keys should be increasing numbers starting from 0. Here is the code I have written in attempt to achieve this:

```
My_dict = {}
count=0

csvfile = pd.read_csv(my_txt)
for idx, column in csvfile.iterrows():
        My_dict[column['Name']].append(count)
        count = count+1
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
KeyError: 'abc_123_def.77'
```

My goal is to generate a dictionary like the following:

{"abc_123_def.77": 1, "abc_123_def.67": 2}

Any insights for me is appreciated. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are instering the data wrong.
try

```py
My_dict[column['Name']] = count
```